# Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix with integer entries and $\det(A) = \pm 1$, then $A^{-1}$ contains all integer entries.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix with integer entries and $\det(A) = \pm 1$, then $A^{-1}$ contains all integer entries.

I'm really thrown off by this one, its unlike all the examples I've seen.. I just dont know where to start... how can I begin to prove this?

Comment: It is also interesting to consider the converse: If you have an integer matrix and its inverse is also an integer matrix, what can you say about the determinants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\text{adj}(A)$.

Comment: ok, so what am I supposed to replace detA with +-1? Ive done a lot of proofs using that formula but I'm not sure how to adapt it to proving A^-1 contains all integer entries.. this is where I'm lost...

Comment: Because the entries of $A$ are integers, the entries of $\text{adj}(A)$ are also integers. And when these integers in $\text{adj}(A)$ are divided by $1$ or $-1$, they remain integers.

Comment: I see. so I guess a complete answer would be to just plug in +-1 into detA, then write what you said, then write "which verifies that A^-1 contains all integers" ?

Comment: You probably also need spend some words to explain why the entries of $\text{adj}(A)$ are integers. In any case, a complete answer should be quite short.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Derive the inverse using [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Inverses).